# wrong values passed in extras.getboolean to other activity

Tags: android-intent

I have two activities, MoneFirst and MOne. 
When i try to start MOne and send the extra info with it the problem occurs in the getBoolean.
events is false and myplace is true. While MOne gets events false and myplace false too. Its taking teh default value maybe. but why?

MOne First:

```
     Intent i = new Intent(MOneFirst.this,MOne.class);
      Log.d("Details of selecting move and view", 
      "Radius is " + r + " Type" + t + "My Events" 
      +events + "My Places" + myplaces );
      i.putExtra("r", r);
i.putExtra("t", t);
i.putExtra("events", events);
i.putExtra("myplaces", myplaces);
startActivity(i);
```

Getting values in MOne:

```
Intent J = getIntent();
Bundle extras = J.getExtras();
r = extras.getDouble("r");
t  = extras.getString("t");
events = extras.getBoolean("events");
myplace = extras.getBoolean("myplace");
```

Im ommitting  the details here and showing "according to me" relevant code.